# jQuery - Data- attribute Quotes Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html, attributes

I'm working on a lightbox script and running into a problem using a custom data-lightbox attribute. What I'm trying to do is allow for the data-lightbox attribute settings to be added dynamically to the page - on an image.

Here's my image:

```
<a href="largeimage.png" data-lightbox='{"setting":"value","setting":"value"}'>
   <img src="thumbnail.png" />
</a>
```

Here's the part of the script that I'm using to inject the settings:

```
$('#testthumbnail').find('a').attr('data-lightbox',settings);
```

Settings is just a string, that is getting dumped into the attribute. When run, I don't receive any errors, and the settings are all injected to the data-lightbox attribute correctly. The settings aren't taking effect in the plugin though for 1 reason - somewhere along the lines the html that gets output to the page looks like this:

```
<a href="largeimage.png" data-lightbox="{"setting":value"}"> ...
```

The surrounding ' ' on the data-lightbox attribute are converted to " " - which won't work in my situation. Does anyone have any idea why the apostrophes are converted to quotes and how I can possibly get around this?
Thanks!

UPDATE:
I have the settings variable available both as a properly formatted JSON string as well as an object. I've tried using both the Object and the string inside the data-lightbox attribute, but am running into the same problem. The browser is converting my ' 's to " "s which is causing JSON errors.

Comment: There is a double quote missing in the first code block after the first occurrence of "value".

Comment: Hey John, thanks I've fixed that, just a typo in the question. I've run through my actual string as well as the object and everything is properly quoted. There also aren't any additional quotes/apostrophes in any other properties/values.

Comment: Not sure that it matters, but I think "data-" attributes should be set with `.data('lightbox', settings)` rather than `.attr('data-lightbox', settings)`.

Comment: I think you're right with the .data, I seem to be getting a bit closer. Thanks!

Comment: Is this the Widgekit Lightbox you are using? I searched for "data-lightbox" and that is all I could find. If so, it doesn't look like it expects JSON. It expects something that looks like a value for a CSS style, where the names and values are not quoted, each name and value are separated by a colon, and the name/value pairs are separated by semi-colons.

Comment: no, it's just a lightbox I'm building. :p thanks though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your quotes are wrong. HTML attributes need to use double quotes. So you need to use the single ones on the JSON value. The browser output you see is the browser trying to do the best it can to correct the html.

Comment: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}'

Comment: [HTML allows single or double quotes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2), but double quotes should be used for JSON.

Comment: ok... confused now. So from what I've been reading and your last comment I believe JSON should be formatted like so: {"setting":"value","setting":"value"}. So, to wrap this inside the data- attribute wouldn't it be surrounded in '{ }' ?

Comment: @maxedison ... If JSON is supposed to be in double quotes, how can I prevent the browser from trying to correct the double quote on the attribute?

Comment: The jQuery API also says to use '{ }' when using JSON inside html5 data- attributes. Not sure why this got upvoted.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in JSFiddle? Seems like a lot of confusion going on around here.

Comment: The quotes are correct, but @maxedison is correct with the browser converting the outer quotes for the attribute to " ". The correct format is single quotes with inner double quotes. I had to find a workaround to avoid using .data and .attr

Comment: Why is this marked as the right answer? HTML attributes CAN use single quotes. And if you need to use double quotes, you can escape JSON's quotes as `ATTR="{&quot;KEY&quot; : &quot;VALUE&quot;}"`. That will also parse the content as JSON object.